# Properly mocking useParams hook in jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock the useParams hook in jest and try to make it dynamic so I can mock it a few times. However, I can only mock it if I hardcode the value. Here's what I got so far:

```
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'), // use actual for all non-hook parts
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
  useParams: () => ({
    hash: '123',
  }),
}));
```

This works because I am hardcoding the useParam to return a `{ hash: '123' }` object.
However, if I try to mock this, it won't work:

```
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'), // use actual for all non-hook parts
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
  useParams: () => jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ hash: '123' })
}));
```

If I do that, my component will receive an empty value and the value wont be mocked the way I want:

```
  const { hash = '' } = useParams<{ hash: string }>();
  console.log('hash: ', hash); ---> ''
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

`useParams` generally returns the route parameters based on the current route. So, it's not a function that can be mocked using `jest.fn()`.
`useParams` hook returns an object of key/value pairs of the dynamic params from the current URL that were matched by the `<Route path>`. See here ---> [React Router docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params)

When you use `jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ hash: '123' })`, it returns a function, not an object. Therefore, calling `useParams<{ hash: string }>()` will result in an empty object `({})`.

To mock `useParams` with a specific value, you can directly return the object with the desired properties. Modify your code below:

```js
    
const mockedUseNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'), // use actual for all non-hook parts
  useNavigate: () => mockedUseNavigate,
  useParams: () => ({ hash: '123' }),
}));
```

This way, when your component calls `useParams<{ hash: string }>()`, it will receive the object `{ hash: '123' }`. No need for the additional `jest.fn()` and `mockReturnValue`.

To mock the `useParams` with dynamic values in Jest, you can use one of the following ways:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter, MemoryRouter, Route, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

// Mock the useParams hook
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  test('renders with dynamic useParams', () => {
    // Set the desired dynamic value for testing
    useParams.mockReturnValue({ hash: '123' });

    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/your-route/123']}>
        <YourComponent />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    // Your testing logic here

    // Ensure that the component received the dynamic value
    const hashValue = screen.getByText(/hash/i).textContent;
    expect(hashValue).toBe('123');
  });
});
```

OR

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import YourComponent from './YourComponent'; // Import your component

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  test('should render with dynamic useParams', () => {
    // Mock the dynamic useParams value
    jest.spyOn(require('react-router-dom'), 'useParams').mockReturnValue({ hash: '123' });

    // Render your component within a Router
    render(
      <Router>
        <YourComponent />
      </Router>
    );
  });
});
```

Here `useParams` is declared outside the `describe()` and its value is change in each unit test using `jest.spyOn`.

OR

```js
let dynamicHash = '123'; // Set your initial value

const mockedUseNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUseNavigate,
  useParams: () => ({ hash: dynamicHash }),
}));
```